# Can't initialize array in C++ using const int value?

Tags: c++

I am making a text based game. I want to make a 2d array of 'Rooms' in my 'GameWorld' class.

I'm used to using C#, but am using C++ in order to learn it. The code I wrote I expected to work, but it gives error as shown in picture. If I write the figures 10 in each array container then it works.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class GameWorld
{
public:
GameWorld();


private:
const int MAP_WIDTH = 10;
const int MAP_HEIGHT = 10;
Room Rooms[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];

};

struct Room {
Room();
std::string Name;
std::string Description;
std::string leftDescription;
std::string rightDescription;
std::string forwardDescription;
std::string backDescription;
//// TODO: Add up and down (potentially need a 3d array map, maybe too complex?
//std::string upDescription;
//std::string downDescription;
};
```

[image]

Is it possible to create arrays this way using const? Or what is the correct way to make the array without hard-coding the size?

Thanks

Comment: Please direct language syntax questions to Stack Overflow, or better yet, search for them first. In a popular language like C++, you'll often find [your exact question has already been answered](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/3mi2jh/trying_to_declare_an_array_using_2_variables/)

Comment: :[ I got banned from Stack Overflow for asking a dumb question lol :| (next time, i will ask it there though using a new account. As completely agree its not really game dev related, more of a language basics kind of question

Comment: Then I recommend amending your use of this network so that you do not get banned from additional sites.

Comment: well tbf, i asked the exact same question here and it was answered in less than an hour without any gripes

Comment: I suggest you fix your questions on SO to have it unbanned instead of circumventing a suspension.

Comment: I'd like to do that. I have had the account for several years. But honestly in the question I got banned for, I thought I had shown lots of steps of research I had already done, and i had been scratching my head for hours all over the exact positions of #includes  (coming in from using C# and Java for years and not having to ever worry about the order of those kind of things, and essentially having it done automatically for me). I didn't think the question was that bad, but went to log in a got notified I can no longer ask questions

Comment: Question bans don't happen overnight, it's not a single bad question that can get you banned, it's accumulation. You migth want to review these "bad" questions and get them in the non-negative score zone. You can also visit the many chat rooms that we have to have your questions answered.

Comment: ok, I will try. Thanks. (From memory only 3 people had seen the question before I got banned). I think i might have upset the wrong person by commenting on a post which was about getting rewarded for marking questions as duplicate , which itself was a duplicate post and I found that funny.

Comment: Regarding "asked the exact same question here", SE doesn't allow cross posting. If you feel that a post on a given SE would be better served on another, flag it for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAP_WIDTH` (and `MAP_HEIGHT`) need to be `static` in this case:

```
static const int MAP_WIDTH = 10;
static const int MAP_HEIGHT = 10;
Room Rooms[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
```

`const` is not declaring *a constant* (in the sense of a fixed value the compiler will simply insert in place of the value's name) in this context. It is indicating that the member variable `MAP_WIDTH` *is* constant and will never change once initialized (it's more akin to C#'s `readonly`, in other words).

Because `MAP_WIDTH` is a member variable, you can't refer to it without having an instance to do `instance.MAP_WIDTH` with. If you use the `static` modifier on variable declaration in a class or struct, that makes the variable a non-member variable, so you can refer to it as you do in the array declaration.

Note that you could consider using [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) instead of [`const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) in this case.

Comment: thank you static constexpr worked for me. I thought it could be done without making them static but now I know :D